# Calibrate an HJM model in a multicurve setup

Tags: models, forward-rate, bootstrapping, heath-jarrow-morton, multicurve

I am a mathematician and I'm working on my thesis on Financial Mathematics.

I studied this model HJM in a multicurve setup:

$$ 
\begin{cases}
df(t,T)=a(t,T)dt+\sigma(t,T)dW_t & (\mbox{rik-free})\\
d\bar{f}(t,T)=\bar{a}(t,T)dt+\bar{\sigma}(t,T)dW_t &(\mbox{risk})
\end{cases}$$
where $W_t$ is $d-$dimensional and $\sigma dW_t$ and $\bar{\sigma}dW_T$ are scalar products.

After studied this model theoretically, I want do to somenthing pratical. After bootstrapped the zero curve and the swap curve how i can calibrate it? I can apply both drift conditions. I can suppose that the dimension is $2$. What I can do with FRA prices or any derivative prices that i can take from Bloomberg to calibrate the model? Suppose that the tenor $\Delta$ is fixed. Example 6 months.

Sorry for my bad English,

Thanks

Comment: HJM is a theoretical framework, hence not used directly in interest rate models, but there are many practical models in the spirit of HJM: LIBOR market model, Swap market model etc, so please google the calibration of these models. Hope this helps!